# DataInputStream readUTF crashing program

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have question, I'm trying to send Map using socket like below

```
 while(scanning){
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            dataInput = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Connected to server");
            receiverThread = new ReceiverThread(clientSocket, dataInput, dataOutput);
            receiverThread.start();
            scanning = false;
            Map<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            jsonMap.put("UserName", "TestName");
            jsonMap.put("FileName", "TestFileName.txt");
            jsonMap.put("FileSize", "1234");

            //sending file
            File f = new File("test.txt");
            System.out.println("F length"+ f.length());
            dataOutput.writeByte(1);
            dataOutput.writeUTF(String.valueOf(jsonMap));
            dataOutput.writeByte(2);
            dataOutput.write(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f.length())));
            //sendFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),f.length(), receiverThread.getDataOutputStream());
            //end sending

        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            System.out.println("Server not available");
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection broken");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR " + e);
        } finally {
            if (receiverThread != null)
                try {
                    receiverThread.interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }
```

and I'm receiving like this

```
while (true) {
        try {
            messageType = dataInput.readByte();
            switch (messageType){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("TEST  " + dataInput.readUTF());
                    message = dataInput.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("TTTT " + message);
                    stringToMap(message);
                    System.out.println("TEST MAP UN1 ");
                    System.out.println("TEST  map " + map.get("UserName"));
                    System.out.println("TEST MAP UN2 ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    saveFile(clientSocket);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + messageType);
            }
            System.out.println("TEST MESSAGE ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            System.out.println("ERROR " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(2);
        }
```

and when i do this :

```
System.out.println("TEST  " + dataInput.readUTF());
```

It's works, but when i try to assigne to String variable program do nothing, it's not crashing, not throwing error just stop on the System.out.println...

someone have any idea why ?

Comment: first off, I don't know what's up with this: `dataOutput.write(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f.length())));` but what you probably want is simply `dataOutput.writeLong(f.length())`. Second, each time you call `dataInput.readUTF()` it tries to read **more** data. It doesn't return the same data each time. The first time you call it in the println it reads properly formatted UTF8-ish data, but the second time it's reading some data that is not properly formatted.

Comment: Yeah, but still as you can see at the begining I'm sending byte (1,2) which is signal for server what kind of data I'm sending. 
And I'm talking about the situation in Case 1: 
`System.out.println("TEST  " + dataInput.readUTF());` this works, but 
line below 
`message = dataInput.readUTF();`
not, program are not doing this

Comment: You're calling `readUTF()` TWICE consecutively. The second call tries to read a UTF8 string but that isn't what was written. So the first two bytes are (2) followed the ASCII character representing the first digit of the file length. It treats this as the length of the string, which is at least 512 because of the (2) bytes. It then tries to read that many bytes, but there are much fewer so it blocks indefinitely.